# Not able to change select box value using select class in Java/webDriver

Tags: java, javascript, xpath, selenium, webdriver

```
<span id="outDuration" class="check_duration last flL" onclick="hideCalendar('#pickUpDate');">
      <label style="width:95px">
      <span class="Class-Outmatch">
             <select id="duration" class="selectBox"  tabindex="7" name="duration">
                         <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
                         <option value="2">2</option>
                         <option value="3">3</option>
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                         <option value="5">5</option>
                         <option value="6">6</option>
                         <option value="7">7</option>
                         <option value="8">8</option>
                         <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
            <span class="left_part flL firefinder-match"></span>
            <span class="selectBox center_part flL selectBox-dropdown" tabindex="7">
                         <span class="selectBox-label">5</span>
```

I am not able to change the value of the select box.
By default value 1 is selected.
If I manually changed it to 5 then the following html code changes the value from 1 to 5.

```
<span class="selectBox-label">5</span>
```

But the option tag attribute `selected` hasn't changed. 
The select tag is invisible.

If following code is used then an exception appears.

```
Select select = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='outDuration']/span/select")).SelectByVisibleText("5");

Exception: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Comment: So, what is this, java or javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `SelectByValue` instead of `SelectByVisibleText`?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: thats one of the problems with this page, it does not allow a newcommer to request additional information by commenting, so they can give a proper answer, since i dont have enough rep i only have 2 options, wait for someone else to request the information witch wont up my rep or do it this way, giving an answer thats not really an answer

Comment: Increasing your reputation..:) @RiccoE

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the select tag is invisble and that's why driver gives you the error that since it is not visible, you cannot interact with it.

Selenium used to allow interaction with hidden elements but not webdriver as it wants to more appropriately simulate user interaction.

To achieve this in webdriver, you need to make the select tag visible first by doing the operation that makes it visible on the page and then use selectbylabel.  Also your xpath seems to be considering the span id whereas select tag itself has an id to identify it.  I would suggest using select's id directly instead of going the relative way.

Answer (score 0):

Use This :

```
Select select=new Select(Utils.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='outDuration']//select[@id='duration']")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("5");
```

If then too you get visibility exception then you would have to go with `JavaScript Executor`.